# Does EF Core offer a clean way to apply FullText Contains AND search?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Suppose I have database table named **Items** that have a Column called **Name**. Inside **Items** I have a chair, which name is '*Black wooden chair*'.

Because there will be millions of **Items**, I have created a Full-Text index on **Name**, to be able to search efficiently. I want a search so that every word of search phrase is contained in the **Name**. For example:

Searching for '*chair wooden*' should return an item with '*Black wooden chair*'  **Name**, but '*chair wooden whatever*' should not return it. Therefore I use a function called '*Contains*' that supports Full-Text search:

```
var userInput = "chair wooden";
var searchQuery = userInput.Split().Aggregate((s1, s2) => "\"" + s1 + "\"" + " AND " + "\"" + s2 + "\"");
   // searchQuery = "chair" AND "wooden"
var result = dbCtx.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => EF.Functions.Contains(i.Name, searchQuery));
```

This just however calls for an SQL injection if user types input such as '*test" AND test*'.
Is there any other way that EF Core could handle such query building for me?

Comment: you could split up the search phrase into a list of search terms and then use `.Where(item => searchTeams.All(term => item.Name.Contains(term)))`

Comment: Unfortunately, regular .Contains does not support full text search, furthermore, expression like .All cannot be translated to database query - I think it might just be done client side, which is not possible here.